# Unfold org subtree containing a special keyword

Tags: org-mode, occur, outline

Consider the following org file:

```
* Heading 1
** Subheading 1.1
** Subheading 1.2 containing Keyword
bar
*** foo
foo
*** bar
**** foo
** Subheading 1.3
* Heading 2
** Subheading 2.1
** Subheading 2.2
* Heading 3
** Subheading 3.1 containing Keyword
foo
** Subheading 3.2 
** Subheading 3.3 containing Keyword
```

How can I unfold all subheadings containing "Keyword" but leave everything else folded?

Maybe even better would be to unfold the subtree produced by `org-occur Keyword` since this hides the other irrelevant subtrees completely.

**Edit**
If I use org-occur for Keyword, it gives me:

```
* Heading 1
** Subheading 1.2 containing Keyword
* Heading 2
* Heading 3
** Subheading 3.1 containing Keyword
** Subheading 3.3 containing Keyword
```

But I want:

```
* Heading 1
** Subheading 1.2 containing Keyword
bar
*** foo
*** bar
* Heading 2
* Heading 3
** Subheading 3.1 containing Keyword
foo
** Subheading 3.3 containing Keyword
```

or with all levels:

```
* Heading 1
** Subheading 1.2 containing Keyword
bar
*** foo
foo
*** bar
**** foo
* Heading 2
* Heading 3
** Subheading 3.1 containing Keyword
foo
** Subheading 3.3 containing Keyword
```

Comment: So what do you want to do differently than what `org-occur` does?

Comment: Org-occur only shows me the subheadings containing the keyword. I want to be able to also see all contents under those subheadings, i.e. unfold it one level further. With optional argument n levels and also as option all levels.